# Simple question, what is meant by 'as $x \to \infty$ the number of squares $\leq x$ is $\sqrt{x} + O(1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, approximation, square-numbers

> For $x \to \infty$:
>   the number of squares $n^2 \leq x$ is $\sqrt{x} + O(1)$.

From [here (page 6).](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.118.4755&rep=rep1&type=pdf)  More specifically, do they mean that... I'm confused now.  I'm really not sure what they mean though I just finished a similar problem.

I know that if '$f$ is $O(g)$' then the limit $\limsup_{x\to \infty} \frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)}$ exists.

Comment: What you know isn't quite so; for instance, the function $f(n)=(-1)^n$ is $O(1)$ even though the limit your definition talks about doesn't exist.

Comment: In this case, it means that if $sq(x)$ is the number of squares $n^2 \leq x$, then there's some constant $C$ and a $x_0$ such that $|sq(x)-\sqrt{x}|\leq C$ (i.e. $C\cdot 1(x)$) for all $x\geq x_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the number of squares $N(x)$. The statement $N(x)=\sqrt{x}+O(1)$ means $N(x)-\sqrt{x}=O(1)$, which is then defined the way that you know, i.e. that $N(x)-\sqrt{x}$ is bounded above and below as $x \to \infty$.

Alternately, you could say that there exists $f$ such that $N(x)=\sqrt{x}+f(x)$ and $f(x)=O(1)$ as $x \to \infty$. This would be useful if somehow the $O(1)$ term entered into the right side in a complicated way, such that you couldn't isolate it.

Comment: In your second paragraph, do you mean to add as $x \to \infty$ in the general case?

Comment: @EnjoysMath Strictly speaking yes. I was leaving it to context, which is sloppy but common practice.

Answer (score 0):

"+O(1)" means "up to addition of a bounded error term".

In this case the error is bounded by $1$.   The $\sqrt{x}$ is a real number that is within $1$ of the exact integer answer.